# How to import a dump of a database with binary files

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have to import a database into phpmyadmin. But the problem is that the creators of the database had the wonderful idea to put some binary files in it. (The field is "tinyblop" type) When I read the dump in notepad++, I have something like:

[image]

So there are special caracters that phpmyadmin can't read. How can I do to correctly import the database ? Even with a long and boring method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to load using mysql console command: `mysql -u USER -p DATABASE < FILE.SQL` or even log into mysql and use `source` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing dumps with Binary data can lead to these problems, that's why you must enable the "hexadecimal output format" so it can be -almost- worry free.

The easiest way and if you only have the phpmyadmin interface: select your database and go to the `import` tab and upload the sql dump file you've got. If it's too big, you can try and zip it, and hopefully it can fit in the buffer (otherwise you'll need to modify some config parameters or chop the file into pieces)

Your best bet is to use a console import (using command line client) since it's faster than phpmyadmin and can handle a dump file of any size :

```
mysql -u USER -p DATABASE < DUMP.SQL
```

or inside the mysql shell do a

```
mysql> source path_to_your_file/dump.sql
```

You can lastly try and ask the creators for another dump with hexadecimal format for binaries. Or you can upload it to a local mysql instance on your machine and do the new dump there.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying but I have some difficulties

Comment: Yep it happens. I've updated the answer so you can use the import tab on phpmyadmin

Comment: I already tried with the phpmyadmin interface but it's where I have the errors.

Comment: Did you try `importing` the file or copying and pasting the sql on a query window? --second option has a higher degree of errors on binary imports--

Comment: I tried with the mysql shell and wrote :  **source C:\Users\Erlaunis\Desktop/persystddo.sql.rar** and I have the error : **ERROR:
ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: 'Rar!'.
Bye**

Comment: Where should I change this oprions please ?

Comment: That's a rar. You need to unrar it, leaving a plain text file with .sql extension. That's the one you want to upload with the shell or with the phpmyadmin import

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101264/discussion-between-erlaunis-and-gusstavv-gil).